# sort multiple columns according to particular order

Tags: matlab, sorting, indexing

I have a matrix

```
A = 1   1   1
    2   2   2
    3   3   3
    4   4   4 
    5   5   5
```

I have 3 arrays containing the orders in which I separately want to sort the respective columns. Example I1 for column 1, I2 for column 2, ....

```
I1 = 5   I2 = 4   I3 = 3
     4        3        2 
     3        2        1
     2        1        5
     1        5        4
```

After sorting the matrix A I should get:-
If only I1 is used to sort the 1st column

```
A = 5   1   1
    4   2   2
    3   3   3
    2   4   4 
    1   5   5
```

If only I2 is used to sort the 2nd column

```
A = 1   4   1
    2   3   2
    3   2   3
    4   1   4 
    5   5   5
```

If only I3 is used to sort the 3rd column

```
A = 1   1   3
    2   2   2
    3   3   1
    4   4   5 
    5   5   4
```

If only I1,I2,I3 is used to sort the all columns

```
A = 5   4   3
    4   3   2
    3   2   1
    2   1   5 
    1   5   4
```

Please suggest me how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If their dimensions are all the same, this should be what you need:

```
A([I1 I2 I3]);
```

If you wish to sort columns individually, you can use this syntax:

```
A(:,2)=A(I2,2);
```

Or e.g. columns 2 and 3:

```
A(:,[2 3]) = [A(I2,2) A(I3,3)];
```

Comment: Its not quite what I wanted. Please check my edited question for better clarity. The sorting of all the columns may not be done simultaneously. Sometimes single column sorting might be required without affecting any one of the other columns.